# SQL join on multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I've got two tables I'm working with

The first one has 6 possible fields called `lt_org_data`
`genre1`, `genre2` ... `genre6` Each record stores an integer value corresponding to a genre they chose and each organization is allowed to pick up to 6 Genre fields.

The second table `ltr_genre` is a reference table with IDs and descriptions.

I need to write a procedure that pulls the data but displays all the other data in `lt_org_data` but replaces the genre `IDs` with `descriptions`. (they can also be null fields because a organization can pick up to 6 but must have 1, so the other 5 can be null).

I have a series of left outer joins but that seems inefficient.

```
select  distinct *
From    lt_org_data a
left outer join ltr_genre b on a.genre1 = b.id
left outer join ltr_genre c on a.genre2 = c.id
left outer join ltr_genre d on a.genre3 = d.id
left outer join ltr_genre e on a.genre4 = e.id
left outer join ltr_genre f on a.genre5 = f.id
left outer join ltr_genre g on a.genre6 = g.id
```

Does anyone have a better way to code this - so that we can do a faster more efficient way.

Thank you.

Comment: The best way would be to normalize your tables instead of having 6 columns for possible genres. What happens when you want to allow 7? You will have to modify the table and all the code. You should instead have an OrganizationGenre table that serves as the bridge for this many to many relationship.

Comment: This is as normalized as we can make it. Each record allows 6 genre options. That is how the program is built. There is no reason to duplicate the other 30 columns sets of data for each genre. besides some times it's important to evaluate the combinations of the genre's. so each line has up to 6. each record stores up to 6 integer values corresponding to a reference table.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. I am by no means suggesting you make yet more copies of your data. I am suggesting you take those 6 columns and move them to a relational table. What you have is not normalized because you have repeating groups. If this was properly normalized this would be simple.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - we thought about that idea except our problem is that the interface we are using to be able to track the data we have to have it all in one localized table, so it wasn't possible to put it into two tables to normalize it that way. but yes that would be ideal.

Comment: Unless you can properly normalize the data you are going to be stuck with 6 left joins to the genre table to get all 6 values.

Comment: I guess then I'm stuck with the six left joins - the data has to be in one table because the user input has to go into one place through the software - so we are limited this way. thank you for the feedback!